# Site redirects to default page after hitting enter in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, redirect

Alright, I have a login page (occurs in register page too) and when I press enter after typing my password to login, it redirects me to the default page but won't do anything else - But when I click the login button, it would login successfully. Why it is happening? Is there a way around it, fixing it?

For example, this is my login.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="התחברות" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageTest.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="login" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <br />
    <center><b>
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
        LoginButtonText="התחבר" PasswordLabelText="סיסמא:" TitleText="<u><font size=4>התחברות</font></u>" 
        UserNameLabelText="שם משתמש:" RememberMeText="זכור אותי" 
        TextLayout="TextOnTop">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" dir="rtl">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <u><font size="4">התחברות</font></u></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">שם משתמש:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">סיסמא:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                        ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1"><font color="red">*</font></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="זכור אותי" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="התחבר" 
                                        ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                        <br />
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ForgotPassLnk" runat="server" Text="שכחתי סיסמא" OnClick="ForgotPassLnk_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</b></center>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

**js**

```
function EnterEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           //login code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean adding this line to the "LoginButton"? Because it didn't really work..

Comment: hmm try second approach

Comment: You want to prevent when enter hit press to submit the form right? Cause second one works for sure [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/na8p004L/1/)

Comment: I want the enter button to fire the login event instead of going to the main page